# Sed regex does not work

Tags: regex, shell, sed

The following command does not return anything and i think my regex is good ?

```
echo 'The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E01.VOSTFR.720p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264-GKS.mkv' |\
sed -n '/The.Big.Bang.Theory*VOSTFR*720p*WEB-DL*.mkv/p'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I dont know sed but I think you missing dot before every * and also I think dots should be with slash

Comment: Torrenting is bad, mmkay. And Big Bang Theory is a terribly vapid show that tries to commoditize geek culture without any deep understanding of it, which it does by trivializing and stereotyping geek culture.


That being sed, .*, not *.

Comment: You ought to just use egrep for this.

Comment: I don't watch TBBT, i hate this TV Show, it's for a friend ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `\.` matches the `.` char
- `.*`  matches **any** char zero or more times:

  `sed -n '/The\.Big\.Bang\.Theory.*VOSTFR.*720p.*WEB-DL.*\.mkv/p'`

Answer (score 0):

`y*` means zero or more `y`s. `R*` means zero or more `R`s. etc.

You probably want

```
/The\.Big\.Bang\.Theory.*VOSTFR*720p.*WEB-DL.*\.mkv/
```

Answer (score 0):

Works like this :

```
echo 'The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E01.VOSTFR.720p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264-GKS.mkv' |\
sed -n '/The.Big.Bang.Theory.*VOSTFR.*720p.*WEB-DL.*.mkv/p'
```

I forgot the dots :/